# How to solve an equation system including log function in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am a beginner to Mathematica. I am trying to get the solution of such equation as:

```
Solve[-b LMR + LMA RGR - a LMR log10[e LMA + (d LMA (1 - LMR) SAR)/RGR] == 0, RGR].
```

Constants are `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`,`LMR`,`LMA`, and `SAR`.
But there seems some error as

> 'Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.'

Who knows how to solve this equation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the [Mathematica Stack Exchange site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/), not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Change log10 to Log10 (Mathematica is FANATIC about correct capitalization) and Solve to Reduce and wait to see whether Reduce can crack it or not.

Comment: Log10 was used, and the system still gave the message as'This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve'.

Comment: And did the substitution of Reduce for Solve and waiting and waiting and waiting to see if Reduce could crack it work or not? Reduce is sometimes more aggressive and has a larger bag of tricks than Solve does. But when a problem includes both RGR and Log[RGR] it is often the case that there is no solution that can be found or that any solution can only be expressed in terms of the Lambert function. You might be able to speed up the process by temporarily combining some independent variables into a single variable. Temporarily combining (d LMA(1-LMR)SAR) into just v1, etc, might speed this up.

Answer (score -1):

On my desk, after substitution --- simply to be clearer --- of RGR by x, Mathematica gives the result

```
Solve[-b LMR + LMA RGR - a LMR Log10[e LMA + (d LMA (1 - LMR) SAR)/x] == 0, x]

{{x -> ConditionalExpression[(
d LMA (-1 + LMR) SAR)/(-10^(-((b LMR - LMA RGR)/(a LMR))) + 
 e LMA), -\[Pi] <= 
 Im[(b LMR - LMA RGR)/(a LMR)] Log[10] < \[Pi]]}}
```

Was the final point in your expression present in your code ?

Comment: `RGR` appears twice in the expression, how is it useful to solve for one of them?